# excess space at the end of the string

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's situation. "Human" attribute may get ID-number value, or string value Name+Surname.

**scenario 1 and 2**

```
  <root> <!--SCENARIO 1 --> 
    <catcher human="generalized value gets from pitcher-1 and pitcher-2"> <!-- condition: at once there could
                                                                                be strictly a) pitcher-1 b) pitcher-2 variant -->
      <pitcher-1 attr-name ="John" attr-surname="Smith" />
      <pitcher-2 /> <!-- note, that there could be an ID attribute and its value, 
                         but not within the same node at the same time in case of pitcher-1's
                         values' presence. And, hence, vice versa. -->        
    </catcher>
    <tail/>
  </root>


  <root> <!--SCENARIO 2 --> 
    <catcher human="generalized value gets from pitcher-1 and pitcher-2">
      <pitcher-1 />
      <pitcher-2 attr-ID="123456"/>
    </catcher>
    <tail />
  </root>
```

My draft xslt to deal with both cases:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- =========== [identity] ============= -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- =========== [identity] ============= -->

<xsl:template match="catcher">
  <catcher human="{pitcher-2/@attr-ID}{pitcher-1/@attr-name} {pitcher-1/@Surname}">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </catcher>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think its a wit situationally finding, but quite weak as a reliable code (anyway it works). The Main problem is that in a case of ID appearing in catcher-element, there is always " "  (space) at the end of the string (space reserved to split Name and Surname).

```
I would appreсiate: 
1) Any solutions to improve this situation
2) typical model\models using for alike cases
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and show a (well-formed) example of the input, with all 3 variants present?

Comment: Michael, comprehensive point is to have possibility to match not only "name" + "surname" values from child node, 
but at any arbitrary position they are. So i would extend previous conditions and re-ask following clarifications:

Comment: - normalizing space method using Xpath sequence with direct (when it known, position in root's hearchy) path to attribute's value/
  (like {../../..}. I tried to extrapolate my {} expression to your solution pattern, but can't 
pick the right punctuation marks. 

as i suppose there could be 2 solution methods
via

solution-1
a) your first sample counting {} {} {} concatination (but how to write it correctly?)
b) using Xpath-axes (different expression consruction) 

solution-2 (most universal)
when we know attribute's name, but don't its position in root's hearchy.

Comment: I am somewhat confused regarding what can and what cannot appear in the input. Is there a scenario where `<catcher human="{normalize-space(concat(pitcher-1/@attr-name, ' ', pitcher-1/@attr-surname, ' ', pitcher-2/@attr-ID))}"/>` would not return the expected result? If yes, please add it to your question, along with the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for help, Michael. Im trying to apply your formula "{normalize-space(concat(pitcher-1/@attr-name,..etc" to my project (yes it keeps Xpath sequences, as i noted) but then all my on-line XSLT-processors show error. Is it standart method (no brackets around attribute's addres, etc) or could be different way to write down the same?

Comment: I see no error: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LVq

Comment: Yes it really works! Mistake was on my side. Missed one symbol which crushed all. Thanks! Btw using https://xslttest.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <catcher>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <surname>Jones</surname>
    </catcher>
    <catcher>
        <ID>200</ID>
    </catcher>
    <catcher>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
    </catcher>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catcher">
    <catcher human="{normalize-space(concat(ID, ' ', name, ' ', surname))}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <catcher human="100 Bob Jones"/>
  <catcher human="200"/>
  <catcher human="John Smith"/>
</root>
```